# Custom Typescript Middleware Pattern

Tags: typescript, generics, middleware

I am implementing a routing library in typescript and want to make sure my middlewares are type safe.
I need the first middleware to take a `Request` and the last one to output a `Response`.

For example

```
// todo
const authoize = (req: Request) => 'token';


// some example middlewares
const log = (req: Request) => {
    console.log(req);
    return req;
}
const auth = (req: Request): [Request, string] => {
    const username = authoize(req);
    return [req, username];
}
const respond = ([_req, username]: [Request, string]) => {
    return new Response(`<h1>hi ${username}</h1>`);
}

// Can I type this for general length?
// An array of functions where each one feeds into the next
type Middlewares<T,S> = [
    (req: Request) => T, 
    (t: T) => S, 
    (s:S) => Response];
// But what about for any number of middlwares?
// I'm not sure if TypeScript can do this for the general case
const middlewares: Middlewares<Request, [Request, string]> = [log, auth, respond];

// loop over middlewares
const handlerLoop = (req: Request): Response => {
    let result = req;
    for (const middleware of middlewares) {
        result = middleware(result);
    }
    return result;
}

// Recursion
const handlerRecursive = (middlewares: Middlewares, memo) => {
    if (middlewares.length === 0) return memo;

    const copy = [...middlewares];
    const first = copy.shift;
    return handlerRecursive(copy, first(memo));
}
```

I cannot work out how I should type the `middlewares` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to correctly apply the generics in your example (however, you'll need to make sure the actual implementations of `f`, `g`, and `h` correspond to those types):

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAYlC8UA8AVAfACgE4QI4C4oAlPAVwgGdgBKBNKFAbgFgAoUSKAcQWRQBooAZUzBCKWvHpCW7cNAASvJCIwVCQyfRIUwAewB2FCLLYATCAGMANgEMcUS4apQAZoRiyLN+9CdHgKABzQi4vKzsHfxcAC0IFU1ZowIBbAEszM2sIAHdfCl4AbVdBIMEYgF1E5KgY2wMsiCxebDxCElxyKmp2yn0jaCkoAG82KCgcYFIsA1qMIIxXVtxqVdkAX1kgA)

```ts
type F = <T>(req: Request) => T;
type G = <T, S>(t: T) => S;
type H = <S>(s: S) => Response;

declare const f: F;
declare const g: G;
declare const h: H;

const middlewares = [f, g, h];

const handler = (req: Request): Response => {
  return h(g(f(req)));
};
```

Comment: Sorry, this is my first SO question - so it's poorly worded!
I want to do the above for arrays of any length.

Comment: I've updated the code snippet, to show how this may look like in use.  TypeScript compiler isn't very happy with it!

Comment: @GuyBalaam That is now an entirely different question. I don't think it's possible for the compiler to serially infer whether, for a tuple of heterogeneous function types, the first parameter of each element is compatible with the return type of the previous. I sincerely hope that I'm wrong and that someone will show us how, but I'm afraid that's unlikely. Here's something that provides a minimal amount of type safety, but won't do exactly what you're asking about: https://tsplay.dev/w24E9m